# Unable to Install spaCy in Conda Env Using Reticulate R Package

Tags: r, spacy, miniconda, reticulate

All. I am trying to install a package in my miniconda environment to be called with Reticulate in R. I am unable to install the package, however.

Here are my steps:

I installed miniconda:

```
install_miniconda(path = miniconda_path(), update = TRUE, force = FALSE)
```

I then created a conda environment:

```
conda_create("test_condaenv")
```

And then installed spaCy in the environment:

```
conda_install("test_condaenv", "spacy")
```

The install seems to complete just fine and I receive no warnings or errors.

But when I try to import spacy I get an error:

```
spacy <- import("spacy")
```

```
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ImportError: cannot import name 'get_terminal_size' from 'click.termui' (/home/username/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/test_condaenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/termui.py)
```

Help is very appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just to write the import and nlp load statements in a python script, then doing `source_python` of the script? That is what I always do when using spaCy in R. Also you could try the `spacyR` package.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I will give `source_python` a shot -- fingers crossed. As for spacyr -- I do typically use that package, but in this special case I need to borrow some functionality from spacy that is not built into spacyr.

Comment: This is related to incompatible versions of `typer` and `click`. Upgrading `typer` is probably the solution.

Comment: This is good to know. I'd like to fix this. Do you know if it is possible to upgrade `typer` from R / Reticulate? I just tried this but it did not work: `conda_install("test_condaenv", "typer")`